# Differences between spread and intersection in HOC flowtype declaration?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype, higher-order-components, flow-typed

I was facing a Flow error regarding the use of a HOC, which just injects a prop, using the following definition:

```
declare function injectFoo<P: {}>(
  Component: React$ComponentType<{ foo: number } & P>
): React$ComponentType<P>;
```

However, Flow stopped complaining when I changed to this version:

```
declare function injectFoo<P: {}>(
  Component: React$ComponentType<{ foo: number, ...P }>
): React$ComponentType<P>;
```

I would think that they are equivalent but guess not. Can someone explain what are the differences or point me in the direction of some documentation?

Flow version: 0.56

P.S.: A real world example of these 2 approaches can be found in the Flow definitions of [withRouter](https://github.com/flowtype/flow-typed/blob/master/definitions/npm/react-router_v4.x.x/flow_v0.53.x-/react-router_v4.x.x.js#L108) (react-router) and [injectIntl](https://github.com/flowtype/flow-typed/blob/master/definitions/npm/react-intl_v2.x.x/flow_v0.53.x-/react-intl_v2.x.x.js#L125) (react-intl) in the flow-typed repo.

EDIT: I've created a clean create-react-app project showing this problem. The project has 2 commits, in the first there are Flow errors which are fixed in the second commit by changing the definition of injectIntl from an intersection to a spread. https://github.com/hyperivo/sandbox-stackoverflow-46591826

EDIT 2: Issue in the flow-typed project: https://github.com/flowtype/flow-typed/issues/1314

Thanks

Comment: I'm also facing same issue. Also I found that if you use `{ foo: number } & $Supertype<P>`, it works. I don't know why.

Comment: But using `{ foo: number, ...P }` causes optional props considered as mandatory and throws flow errors.

Answer (score 0):

That's really weird 
I think this one's a bug in `flow-typed`.
It could also be a bug in `flow` itself, but since it just works in the [flow.org/try](https://flow.org/try) sandbox, my first thought would be that it's in `flow-typed`?
Or it could be a bug in the [flow.org/try](https://flow.org/try) sandbox maybe?

What I would suggest is that you report an issue in the `flow-typed` repo (maybe also post the link here for further documentation) and then the `flow` team will figure it out for sure

**Previous answer:**

> After looking at your screenshot, I'm guessing you're using an i18n
>   package? (`react-intl`?)   So what I think is that you're not
>   providing the correct props for the i18n into the component.
>
> **Original answer:**
>
> > Both versions are basically the same and both work in `flow v0.56.0`,
> >     like you can see on [flow.org/try](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQATApgY2gQwE6tJAK4B26ALgJazGgXEBWGZAYrLADwAKAXKAN4BfAHwAKRKFABhWAFsADtVTEyvAEqos5ACTT5i5QBUAnnNTs+BNr2KEZAI1Q5QA0ADJQnIYgCUajdt0FYiUyY1MuIQBuRBQMbDwCEnIqGjpGclYOHn5hMQlA-RVQdU0yHVkgkLCzC0grUBt7RwAaUAA6Ds5nL19i-zKC4MMTM09IoA)

Comment: indeed I could not replicate the errors in the sandbox, but changing from the first version to the second removes the errors you see here https://pasteboard.co/GNyLI1W.png :\

Comment: Added my thoughts to my answer 

Comment: Hi @MichaelDeBoey, I added a github project showing the problem

Comment: @ianastacio I've added my thoughts to my answer 